# How do I view a file's hard links in Windows?

Tags: windows, hardlink

I've found a [description of hard links and junctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365006%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in Windows, however I'd like to know ,from the Windows UI or command prompt, how I can view the hard links of a particular file or folder?

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "view" in this context?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The [`fsutil` utility](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753059%28v=ws.11%29.aspx) included in Windows XP and higher. Example:

```
fsutil.exe hardlink list C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe
```

Sample results (from Windows 7):

```
\Windows\System32\notepad.exe
\Windows\notepad.exe
\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-notepadwin_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_none_9ebebe8614be1470\notepad.exe
\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-notepad_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_none_cb0f7f2289b0c21a\notepad.exe
```

Comment: Is there also any way to list *soft links* and *junctions* for a file?

Comment: Looks like on Server 2003 fsutil doesn't support the `hardlink list` subcommand. Only `hardlink create` is shown by `fsutil hardlink`.

Answer (score 11):

`fsutil` requires elevated system privileges. If you just need to read, and not create, links this is very inconvenient.

Microsoft releases also the free [findlinks](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/hh290814),   which is  much more syntax  friendly, gives extra-details and does not require special privileges.

Judge yourself the same file, as from John K post,  analysed with `findlinks`:

```
findlinks c:\windows\notepad.exe

FindLinks v1.0 - Locate file hard links                                                             
Copyright (C) 2011 Mark Russinovich                                                                 
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com                                                                 
                                                                                                    
c:\windows\notepad.exe                                                                              
        Index:  0x000037A6                                                                          
        Links:  3                                                                                   
                                                                                                    
Linking files:                                                                                      
c:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe                                                                     
c:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-notepadwin_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_none_9ebebe8614
be1470\notepad.exe                                                                                  
c:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-notepad_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_none_cb0f7f2289b0c
21a\notepad.exe
```

## EDIT

While the convenience of `findlinks` might persist,

> starting with Windows 10 Insiders build 14972, symlinks can be created without needing to elevate the console as administrator.

See [blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2016/12/02/symlinks-windows-10/)

One can also observe that now `fsutil.exe` does not require elevated privileges any more.

Microsoft's goal is to align the symlinks functionality to Linux standards, where they are very common.

Thanks to
[pinjaliina](https://serverfault.com/users/278468/pinjaliina)
for pointing out this.

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 20H2, and `fsutil.exe` didn't require elevated privileges anymore. [There are some changes to symlink permissions in general in Windows 10](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2016/12/02/symlinks-windows-10/), perhaps that's why. I don't even have Developer Mode enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly what you need but may still be useful for such goal when used cleverly:
**[FINDDUPE](http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/finddupe/)**, a standalone command line utility hosted at http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/finddupe/ address, has side functionality, which allows listing all hardlinks within a directory recursively with the following call:
`finddupe -listlink <directory_of_interest>`

Here is an example of what one gets as an output:

```
Hardlink group, 2 of 2 hardlinked instances found in search tree:
  ".\1"
  ".\_1"

Number of hardlink groups found: 1
```

*NOTE: There is a number of projects with the similar name on SourceForge, but nothing actually hosts the utility above as for now.*

Answer (score 1):

The [FindLinks](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/findlinks) tool from Sysinternals should be exactly what you need.

```
findlinks C:\Windows\notepad.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`ln` CLI utility](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/ln/ln.html) by Hermann Schinagl should work:

```
ln --list
```

There's also a [shell extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html).

Comment: Thx for the link to this commandline tool :D

Answer (score 0):

Try the program [NTFSLinksView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/ntfs_links_view.html) - works fine for me on Windows 10, should work on Vista and later.